# Call to a member function getId() on null - module-catalog/Helper/Product.php

Tags: magento2

I added sample data to my magento2 website, but when I want to access to a product I always get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null
>   in
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product.php:313
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product.php(430):
>   Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product->canShow(NULL) #1
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(263):
>   Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product->initProduct(1562,
>   Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)) #2
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php(118):
>   Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View->prepareAndRender(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor),
>   1562, Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)) #3
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108):
>   Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View->execute() #4
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framewor in
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product.php on
>   line 313

The Product.php code :

```
public function canShow($product, $where = 'catalog')
    {
        if (is_int($product)) {
            try {
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
       /*313*/     if (!$product->getId()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $product->isVisibleInCatalog() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
    }
```

when I `var_dump($product)` it's return `NULL`

Product.php class code : https://snipsave.com/saadsaad/#/snippet/iDIEafixLtWgzWO9sK

is there any solution?

Comment: It can be an indexing issue did you reindexed the site after the sample data deployment?

Comment: I lunch this command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but still not work

Comment: did you check the `$product` like `print_r($product)` to check that  the data is coming in in your `$product` or not

Comment: Id suggest redeploying your site if it still doesnt work try accessing the site via the admin and seeing if you can access the products via the admin if so save one via the admin and try and review that product

Comment: @AsadKhan I don't really understand what you mean, but I get the list of products on the home page, but when I try to a specific one I get this error

Comment: @DavaGordon I can edit a product from admin panel

Comment: Id check the show in website settings to make sure that it is selected if so remove it and save then reselect it as the error is stating the ID and canShow are null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search, I found that the problem was on di.xml

because I added this:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" 
        type="Testing\HelloWorld\Model\CustomImplementation" />
```

so I remove it and it's work

Comment: I am getting the same kind of error using paypal, could you pls help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/64463480/11697039 @sayou Thanks

Comment: @zus I apologize for being late, but unfortunately, my current job is very far from Magento 2, by the way, do not forget to share the solution with the rest, if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from `if (!$product->getId())` to `if (!$product)` it should work

complete code would be:

```
public function canShow($product, $where = 'catalog')
{
    if (is_int($product)) {
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
   /*313*/     
        if (!$product) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $product->isVisibleInCatalog() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
}
```

Comment: I do it, but when I access to a product I get 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
**`null`** will be returned if the object is **`null.`**

```
public function canShow($product, $where = 'catalog')
    {
        if (is_int($product)) {
            try {
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
                return $product ? $product->getId() : null;
        }
        return $product->isVisibleInCatalog() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
    }
```

Comment: It's get a 404 page

Comment: better if you can post your whole Product class so that we can check why it returns 404

Comment: @magefms I added the product.php code

Comment: @sayou I tried your code but it works. kindly double check if you have some custom class that extends product helper class

Comment: @magefms, yes sir I found the error on di.xml on this code `<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Testing\HelloWorld\Model\CustomImplementation" />`